# python-sphinx autosummary for private members

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm trying to use python sphinx sphinx.ext.autosummary extension, but have a problem that it doesn't create entries for private members in generated tables. I mean generally for modules, functions and so on which names starts with underscore.

I know I can mark private members as non private, but I don't want to do so.

I've tried also autodocs option `autodoc_default_options`, but set `'private-members': True` doesn't help. I can change autosummary module template and insert there something like:

```
.. automodule:: {{ fullname }}
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :private-members:
```

After that it includes private member documentation, but the generated summary tables include only public members.

The `autosummary` directive doesn't accept `:private-members:` option.

How can I force it to create summary for private modules and other members too?

Comment: I think that `version` and `copyright` are reserved variables in Sphinx. For documenting private members, are they inherited? If so, then use `:inherited-members:` flag. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_default_flags

Comment: @StevePiercy ok. I've found autodoc can't deal with undocumented module constants and variables at all